# this weekday or these weekdays?

Tags: word-usage

I am thinking if I want to specifically point out that **"I am not available on weekdays this week."**

Can I just say that **"I won't be available these weekdays?"** or should i just use the sentence that I wrote above?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using the phrase "these weekdays" implies that you are referring to *specific* weekdays. For example, you might have discussed specific ones, or you might be pointing to some on a calendar.

Your first sentence is absolutely fine, but native speakers might say:

> I am not available **in/during the week** this week

Or of course you could be more direct:

> I am only available on the weekend this week
>
> I am not available Monday to Friday this week

Comment: +1 for advocating specificity and directness

Comment: I am a little confused with the part that " in/during the week this week." Do you mean "in/during the weekday(s) this week" ?

Comment: @Yung That's what it means, yes. We'll often say "in the week" to mean Monday to Friday.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning, though, that using "in the week" to mean Monday through Friday is more common in a workplace, especially one that has those workdays. It might be confusing if a nurse or firefighter said that, or even my spouse at home, but it would sound perfectly normal coming from a co-worker in the office.

Comment: @J.R. I'd disagree with that; I hear it equally in, and out of, work, and no context has been confusing.

Comment: @Dan - I have one daughter who works erratic 12-hour shifts as a night shift nurse, and another who works a [2-2 3-2 2-3 schedule](https://www.bmscentral.com/learn-employee-scheduling/2-2-3-2-2-3-rotating-shift/) at an airport. If either one of them said to me on a Wednesday, "Sorry, I am not available during the week this week," I would have to ask them for clarification. (However, if my son – who works at the local high school – said the same thing, I would know exactly what he meant.)

Comment: @J.R. Personally I still think that's anecdata away from the norm, but we'll agree to disagree on this.

Comment: @Dan - I wholly agree that it’s anedata away from the norm. I wasn’t disagreeing with your answer, I was merely pointing out what I thought would be an uncommon exception that might be of interest to a learner.